# Dark manhwa/webtoon about a girl who meets her alleged future husband, who has actually time traveled to find his twin's killer

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I'd like to ask for help finding a webtoon/manhwa.
The story might be a bit all over the place, but I remember all of it quite well.

It is set in high school, the main character is a female (I shall call her Y) who is approached by someone who claims to have married her in the future, I shall call him X. She recognises him as her classmate (Z).

Later, it is seen that X is, in fact, Z's twin who time travels from the future to find Z's killer. Y, however, does not know this, and falls in love with X.

The story is a bit dark, and I can provide some more miscellaneous information if anyone needs it.
I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?  Please provide all the miscellaneous information you can; the more details we have the better.

Comment: I have the name now, but X is kept a secret from Y because X and Z aren't on the best terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[Boy From the Future](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/boy-from-the-future)*. It is licensed by [Manta](https://manta.net/en/series/boy-from-the-future?seriesId=1202).

> High school students Dain Son and Sihyun Lee could hardly be called close. One day, **Dain is approached by a man who claims to be Sihyun from the future. What’s more, he says they end up dating and he has traveled back in time to stop a murder**. As Dain and “future Sihyun'' become more involved, Dain and “present Sihyun”’s friendship also changes. What will become of such entangled relationships? How will the future change?

The synopsis is a perfect match for the question. The first chapter has the protagonist borrow money from a classmate and runs outside to buy an umbrella due to the sudden rain. She meets an older man who states that he time traveled and needs her help, and that they're dating in the future.

[image: Boy from the future]

To prove that he's real, he predicts that she will shortly lose her phone and nearly get hurt. Someone immediately throws a brick towards her, which he saves her from, and secretly steals her phone while she's distracted.

Back in the classroom, another classmate talks to the boy and discovers that he has a twin brother, which he emphatically denies and insists she not tell anyone.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `twin/s` and `time travel`.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so very much. 